# img not displaying (img src file path wrong?)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image

this is my header.js

```
<div className="navbar">
      <header>
        <div>
          <img src="../Images/coatHanger.svg" alt="coatHanger" />
          <h1>E-commerce</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className="nav-items">
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
```

this is my file structure

```
src
|Components
||Header.js
|Images
||coatHanger.svg
|App.js
|Index.js
```

this is the css for the img

```
img[alt="coatHanger"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

I have tried "./Images/coatHanger.svg" and "/Images/coatHanger.svg" but those don't work either.

Edit:Thanks now it works.
Using import

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? if you using webpack, make sure you install [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

Comment: try this: `<img src="src/Images/coatHanger.svg" alt="coatHanger" />`

Comment: @davoodSandoghsaz — That won't work. Try reading the duplicate question.

Comment: It works now with importing the img